# SAS on OS X any way to run without working within virtual machine?

Tags: macos, sas, virtual-machine

I would like to edit and submit SAS code from emacs (aquamacs) on OS X to SAS running on Vista (through Parallels).  Any idea how to do this?  I like to do everything through one place and it is really annoying to work within the windows emulator.

I have run SAS from a linux server through aquamacs but wonder if something similar can be done locally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look into setting up the ability to execute remote shell commands on the windows side.  You could then setup emacs/aquamacs make the remote shell call.

Just throwing this idea out there...  I don't actually know if this is possible but conceptually it should work fine...

Comment: yeah it does seem like it should work conceptually but putting into action is the hard part.

Comment: You're right, seems that unless you have Enterprise or Ultimate edition of vista you will either have to try the Windows 2000 Resource Kit tools or a 3rd party app.

There's a good overview of your options here: http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/92667-rsh-console.html